# Excel VBA UserForm, Need to create new ID every time form is called and save it on Add/Save button click

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a simple UserForm to enter new customer details to the Customer List in the spreadsheet, form works fine except for one little thing, which is New Customer ID.

Basically what I need this for to do is once form is opened/called new customer ID need to be created, which could be and Alfa numerical set of characters like AA-01234, AA-01235, AA-01236 and so on.

Also, is there a way of posting newly added Customer ID in the `MsgBox` along with `MsgBox "One record added to Customers List. New Customer ID is "`

All of my attempts to create this are failing and causing errors, which I really cannot figure out since I am new to VBA and had never used it until now.

Please help me a little.

Here is my code, Customer ID is TextBox1.

Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Customers")

    RefNo.Enabled = True
    'find last data row from database
    iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    If ws.Range("A" & iRow).Value = "" Then
        RefNo.Text = "TAS1"
        ws.Range("A" & iRow).Value = RefNo
    Else
        RefNo.Text = "TAS" & Val(Mid(ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value, 4)) + 1
        ws.Range("A" & iRow + 1).Value = RefNo
    End If
    TextBox1.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("Customers!A8:A65536")) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub Addreccord_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Object

    Set LastRow = Range("Customers!A65536").End(xlUp)

    LastRow.Offset(1, 0).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("Customers!A8:A65536")) + 1
    LastRow.Offset(1, 1).Value = TextBox2.Text
    LastRow.Offset(1, 2).Value = TextBox3.Text
    LastRow.Offset(1, 3).Value = TextBox4.Text
    LastRow.Offset(1, 4).Value = TextBox5.Text
    LastRow.Offset(1, 5).Value = TextBox6.Text
    LastRow.Offset(1, 6).Value = TextBox7.Text
    LastRow.Offset(1, 7).Value = TextBox8.Text
    LastRow.Offset(1, 8).Value = TextBox9.Text
    LastRow.Offset(1, 9).Value = TextBox10.Text
    LastRow.Offset(1, 10).Value = TextBox11.Text

    MsgBox "One record added to Customers List"

    response = MsgBox("Do you want to enter another record?", _
              vbYesNo)

    If response = vbYes Then
        TextBox1.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("Customers!A8:A65536")) + 1
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        TextBox7.Text = ""
        TextBox8.Text = ""
        TextBox9.Text = ""
        TextBox10.Text = ""
        TextBox11.Text = ""

        TextBox2.SetFocus

    Else
       Unload Me
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Exitform_Click()
    End
End Sub
Sub ClearFields_Click()
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
            Case "TextBox"
                ctrl.Text = ""
        End Select
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? And at which line exactly?

Comment: Actually I have just managed to sort that part out, but still cannot get it to work with alpha numeric characters, only works with numeric

Comment: AlphaNumeric surely wont work with MAX, you shoukld create a function with some logic that ensures you a unique ID every time you call it and create a private form field that stores its value each time a new record is demanded

Comment: For your alfanumerical example it could be possible, removing the Alfa part and getting max from the numerical part

Comment: @Roger Thanks for your response, but where do I start and how should I do this?

Comment: @Roger, I have tried to do what you have suggested, but having Runtime error 424, Object is required, can you please recommend something? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Create a Named Range**

To simplify your code, I would create a NamedRange called *CustomerIDList*.

So, instead of saying:

```
    Range("Customers!A8:A65536")
```

you'd be able to put:

```
    Range("CustomerIDList")
```

In this picture the rows are hidden, but notice how the range selected is called *CustomerIDList*.

[image: excel named range]

Then, when the UserForm is activated, it will use a function to return AA-66763 (one more than the max value in *CustomerIDList*)

[image: excel userform]

**Step 2: Use a custom function to split on hyphen**

RegEx (Regular Expressions) could give you full control, but here's a solution using your own defined function.

This function relies on Excel's built-in FIND() function and uses VBA's Right() and Len() functions.

I'm assuming the following:

- your Worksheet is named Customers
- Range("A8") is where your values start (same as saying row 8, column 1)
- Values in Column A are contiguous
- **Format of Values is *AA-01234***

For this function to work, it requires five inputs (i.e. arguments):

- sheetName
- nameOfRange
- rowStart
- colStart
- delimeterToSplitOn

  *CustomerIDList* is a name I chose for the Range, but it could be anything you want.

  ```
  Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

      TextBox1.Value = "AA-" & GetCustomerId("Customers", "CustomerIDList", 8, 1, "-")

  End Sub
  ```

```
    Public Function GetCustomerId( ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal nameOfRange As String, ByVal rowStart As Long, ByVal colStart As Long, ByVal delimeterToSplitOn) As Long

       'Just creating a Range object, assigning it all the values of CustomerID, and naming the Range
        Dim r1 As Range

        Set r1 = Range(Cells(rowStart, colStart), Cells(rowStart, colStart).End(xlDown))

        With ActiveWorkbook.Names

            .Add Name:=nameOfRange, RefersTo:="=" & sheetName & "!" & r1.Address & ""

        End With


        'This array holds all original AlphaNumeric Values
        Dim AlphaNumericArr() As Variant

        'This array will hold only the Numeric Values
        Dim NumericArr() As Variant


        'Populate Array with all the values
        AlphaNumericArr = Range(nameOfRange)

        'Resize NumericArr to match the size of AlphaNumeric
        'Notice, this is an index of 1 because row numbers start at 1
        ReDim NumericArr(1 To UBound(AlphaNumericArr, 1))

        Dim R As Long
        Dim C As Long
        For R = 1 To UBound(AlphaNumericArr, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
            For C = 1 To UBound(AlphaNumericArr, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.

                'Uses one worksheet function: FIND()
                'Uses two VBA functions: Right() & Len()

                'Taking the original value (i.e. AA-123980), splitting on the hyphen, and assigning remaining right portion to the NumericArr
                NumericArr(R) = Right(AlphaNumericArr(R, C), Len(AlphaNumericArr(R, C)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(delimeterToSplitOn, (AlphaNumericArr(R, C))))

            Next C
        Next R



        'Now that have an array of all Numeric Values, find the max value and store in variable
        Dim maxValue As Long
        Dim i As Long

        maxValue = NumericArr(1)

        For i = 1 To UBound(NumericArr)

            If maxValue < NumericArr(i) Then
            maxValue = NumericArr(i)
            End If

        Next

        'Add 1 to maxValue because it will show in UserForm for a new CustomerID
        GetCustomerId = maxValue + 1


    End Function
```

**UPDATE:**

This is how you would change your existing code so that it works.  Notice, the MsgBox now shows the id, too.

```
    Private Sub Addreccord_Click()
        Dim LastRow As Object

        Set LastRow = Range("CustomerIDList").End(xlDown)

        LastRow.Offset(1, 0).Value = "AA-" & GetCustomerId("Customers", "CustomerIDList", 8, 1, "-")

        LastRow.Offset(1, 1).Value = TextBox2.Text
        LastRow.Offset(1, 2).Value = TextBox3.Text
        LastRow.Offset(1, 3).Value = TextBox4.Text
        LastRow.Offset(1, 4).Value = TextBox5.Text
        LastRow.Offset(1, 5).Value = TextBox6.Text
        LastRow.Offset(1, 6).Value = TextBox7.Text
        LastRow.Offset(1, 7).Value = TextBox8.Text
        LastRow.Offset(1, 8).Value = TextBox9.Text
        LastRow.Offset(1, 9).Value = TextBox10.Text
        LastRow.Offset(1, 10).Value = TextBox11.Text

        MsgBox "One record added to Customers List.  New Customer ID is " & LastRow.Offset(1, 0).Value
```

Comment: Thanks so much, just one question, should I replace underscores in      ByVal sheetName As String, _
     ByVal nameOfRange As String, _
     ByVal rowStart As Long, _
     ByVal colStart As Long, _
     ByVal delimeterToSplitOn) As Long with my values like, Worksheet Customers, range _customerID and so on?

Comment: @AlexB You're welcome.  No, the underscores are just for multi-line concatenation in VBA.  I'll update it to remove those so it's less confusing. To pass your own arguments, you'd write something like: `Call GetCustomerId("Customers", "CustomerIDList", 8, 1, "-")`

Comment: OK, but I have an error on the following line NumericArr(R) = Right(AlphaNumericArr(R, C), Len(AlphaNumericArr(R, C)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(delimeterToSplitOn, (AlphaNumericArr(R, C)))), any ideas?

Comment: @AlexB Do all values in ColumnA start with a format similar to AA-?  It'd help if you could show me the actual data.  What is the error specifically?

Comment: Currently there is no values in the column A and yes they all should start from AA-. The error I have is Unable to get the Find property of the WorksheetFunction class. If you use TeamViewer I can show you.

Comment: @AlexB I didn't put any error checking in the function itself.  As the code is written, you must have at least one value starting in Range("A8") on a worksheet named 'Customers'.  So, on Range("A8"), just put in one row and test it out small (see the picture)

Comment: OK, is there any way to correct the issue with adding the first entry and ID by using form or at list creating one field on the settings page so that the first ID can be copied from that field in case if user wanted to use BR instead of AA? or is it too much to ask?

Comment: @AlexB I'm emailing it back.  It'd be possible to do what you want, but that's getting pretty specific.  The way it is coded, the worksheet must start with at least two records already prepopulated in the table.

Comment: use `With ... End With` block for `LastRow ` will make the code look cleaner and gain a bit of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I shortened your code. I think your problem is in the `Addreccord_Click()` sub. Does this work for you?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LastRow As Range

    Set LastRow = Range("A8").End(xlDown)
    LastRow.Offset(1, 0).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("Customers!A8:A65536")) + 1
    LastRow.Offset(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text

    MsgBox "One record added to Customers List"

    response = MsgBox("Do you want to enter another record?", _
              vbYesNo)

    If response = vbYes Then

    Else
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not too sure if that can help me with what I actually need to do.